# Rewrite MVC URL to different directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

At the moment I have a PHP MVC project that needs to have URL rewriting for better usability. However, the project can be installed in different directories and I am unable to write a proper working .htaccess that can handle both cases:

1. /var/www/html/testapp/ - Direct access: 127.0.0.1/testapp
2. /var/www/html/specific_installation_number_4 - Virtual host: www.testapp4.org

As you can see, I have to different base URIs. The project structure looks like this:

```
testapp/
    index.php
    .htaccess
    public/
        css/
            style.css
        js/
            script.js
    vendor/
        frameworks/
            jquery/
        twitter/
            bootstrap/
```

index.php:

```
<?php

echo("GET: ");
var_dump($_GET);
echo("<br>URI: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="vendor/frameworks/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/script.js"></script>
        <link href="vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Testapp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testapp</h1>
        <p>Not implemented yet!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess (Trial and error...):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So the idea is that REQUEST_URI should have the following values:

```
(empty) (System will use the fallback controller)
mycontroller
mycontroller/action
mycontroller/action/42
```

Question:

1. Can anyone post/hint me to a working version?
2. Can anyone explain me the idea/used syntax in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I really gave up the possibility to rewrite from two different directories aka two different base URIs. I just added a virtual host to my local system (www.test.com). For interested people, the .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Skip the public and vendor directories
RewriteRule ^(public|vendor)($|/) - [L]

# Skip existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite the URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Note: The input source of additional files like js, css, images etc. needs to be absolute:

```
<link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```